# Combine TextBoxes into one from an ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, itemscontrol, multibinding

Is there a way to combine all the textboxes that this itemscontrol creates so I can select them all as in a single textbox or textblock? As of right now, I can only select the text in a single textblock at a time.

```
<ItemsControl Background="WhiteSmoke" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItemNotes}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBox IsReadOnly="True" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0">
                    <TextBox.Text>
                        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1} - {3}">
                            <Binding Path="Timestamp" />
                            <Binding Path="UserName" />
                            <Binding Path="Notes" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </TextBox.Text>
                </TextBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

So as far as text selection interaction goes, you want the user to interact with the text in multiple text boxes it as if it were all in one big multi-line textbox: User clicks between the fourth and fifth characters in the first box, drags to just before the ninth character in the third box, and releases the left mouse button. The result is that everything after the fourth character in the first text box is selected, all of the second text box is selected, and the first eight characters of the third are selected.

There's nothing that'll do that for you. You'd be writing custom mouse interaction. I've done text selection with a mouse, though only in a single control, and it's finickier than you realize, but it's pretty awesome when it's finally working right.

So you'd set up some private state in your control class so the mouse events know that the user is engaged in this mega-selection interaction. Mousedown and drag in a textbox in the ItemsControl would launch that, mouseup in one would end it.

On mousemove, you'll have to set SelectionStart/SelectionEnd for each of the textboxes between the one you started at, and the one you're over. For the one you're over (if it's not the first one), you'll have to do custom code to find out which character the mouse is over, and programmatically set SelectionStart and SelectionEnd.

Don't forget that the user can drag-select "upward" from TextBox 2 to TextBox 0 you need to know which way the selection is going.

Once you know which textboxes are in your selection, write a property that enumerates those. Given that, once they have the appropriate text selected, it's easy to get the full selection text:

```
//  In order of first in UI to last, regardless of "selection direction"
protected IEnumerable<TextBox> MegaSelectionTextBoxes {
    get {
        //  Whatever -- might be a good idea to keep them 
        //  in a List<TextBox> or ObservableCollection<TextBox>
    }
}

//  The easy part
public String MegaSelectionText {
    get {
        return 
            String.Join("\n",
                        MegaSelectionTextBoxes.Select(
                            tb=>tb.SelectedText));
    }
}
```

Myself, I wouldn't count on getting that working really right in less than a week. Your definition of "right" may be a lot more permissive though.

But I would prefer an approach that works with XAML rather than trying to work around it.

If it were me, unless this feature was really critical for some reason (and sometimes they are), I'd make a case to sacrifice the partial selection in the first and last textboxes in the selection.

I'd look at using a multiselect ListBox rather than an ItemsControl, so I could let the user select items. Then I'd bind `SelectedItems` on the ListBox to an `ObservableCollection` on my viewmodel, and write a Command on my viewmodel that does whatever I want with the concatenated text of all the selected items.

Another option is use a DataGrid which multiple cell selection. That'll get you the interaction you want, though you may have to play some games to get it to look the way you want it to.

Comment: Selecting might not have been the right word to choose. I want to be able to highlight all the text, as in click and drag to select all the text in the textbox. Would that be possible using a multi-select listbox ?

Comment: @Rob Updated my answer to address that scenario. Good luck! This looks like a pretty fun (read: painful but rewarding) feature, if there's a solid business case for spending the time on it.

Comment: I decided to just use a StringBuilder and append all the values in my ViewModel and output a large string with new lines.. Which gets all the text that I want in a single textbox.. but would it be possible though to Dynamically change the color of certain words on the string? Without using any code-behind using databinding and MVVM ? I need to be able to change the color per User for each note.

Comment: The [WebBrowser control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx) might be a good bet: Make a ViewModel property that returns HTML-formatted colored text, and stuff that into a WebBrowser control.  Does it need to be editable in the UI? If so, try [RichTextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx). But making it editable gets into horrible issues with figuring out which note the user is changing. I'd keep this part read-only and if editing is a requirement, do it elsewhere.